# Remove p tags in wordpress posts

Tags: wp-autop

WORDPRESS VERSION: 3.8.1
PHP version:  5.3

I have a trouble with wordpress posts. How can I remove the auto P tags added?
This is my final html code:

```
<div class="one_half_style_4_last">
<p>
<p>
<ul class="list-green">
<p>
<h4 class="\"pattern-bg-title-grey\"">
<span>Livelli Vip</span>
</h4>
<div class="su-table table-post">
<h4 class="\"pattern-bg-title-grey\"">
<p></p>
<p>Invalid Displayed Gallery</p>
<p></p>
<h4 class="\"pattern-bg-title-grey\"">
<p></p>  
<div class="srp-widget-container">
<p></p>
<p class="omc-single-tags"></p>
<br class="clear">
<div class="omc-related-posts">
</div>
```

There is another trouble, wordpress add slashes (magic_quotes_gpc on my server is Off):

```
<h4 class="\"pattern-bg-title-grey\"">
```

I tried to put this code in functions.php or single.php and even comment these lines in wp-includes/default-filters.php but is not working:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

What can i do?

Comment: I tried to write in the post:
<h4 class='pattern-bg-title-grey'><span>Articoli</span></h4>
with only one quote and now the trouble is fixed but i don't know why is a problem if I use double quotes... it's a mistery. Incredible... before i hadn't this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... I fixed the second trouble!
The problem was a option in this plugin: SEO Smart Links

I disabled this field: Prevent linking in heading tags (h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6)

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress implementation of the TinyMCE editor [automatically adds `<p>` tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE#Automatic_use_of_Paragraph_Tags). There's a few options for removing, as explained in [a tutorial on removing `<p>` tags](http://redrokk.com/2010/08/16/removing-p-tags-in-wordpress/).

I would recommend the [following approach](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-wpautop-filter), which is a slight modification from that tutorial (as it involves messing with core wp functions). Add the following code to your `functions.php` file which removes the auto `<p>`'s:

```
function rm_wpautop($content) {
    global $post;
    // Remove the filter
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    return $content;
}

// Hook into the Plugin API
add_filter('the_content', 'rm_wpautop', 9);
```

Alternatively, if you only wanted to remove the auto `<p>` tags on specific posts or pages or other parts of your theme template, look for the line `<?php the_content(); ?>` in your template files and add `<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>` before it.

Comment: Hi, i tried but is not working.. if i put this code into the functions.php file, the website doesn't load (blank page). :/
I even tried to put remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); before it but is not working.
[link](http://www.italiapokerblog.it/poker-room/pokerstars/)

Comment: I've tested this code and it 100% works. Make sure it is placed in your functions file before the closing php tag `?>`

Comment: yes before the tag ?> but is not working and i don't know why... the other problem is the slashes added before the double quotes. I'm becoming crazy today

Comment: If your page is blank - that generally means that you have a PHP error happening, and `display_errors = Off` in your `php.ini` file. It's probably a simple syntax issue.

Comment: no blank page now but is not working as well. There is another problem -> <h4 class="\"pattern-bg-title-grey\"">
Wordpress added the slashes, why?

Comment: Are you entering your HTML into the "Text" tab of the WordPress Editor?

Comment: Also be sure to [mark this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it has answered your original question! Cheers